# Change Dashboard's map with ArcGIS Python API

Tags: arcgis-python-api, operations-dashboard

Is it possible to change the map used in a Dashboard with the ArcGIS Python API?
I know it can be done manually by changing the map's id in the ArcGIS Online Assistant, but I would like to do this automatically.

Updating other item's (like web map or feature layer) properties can be done with the `.update()` method, I'd like to do something similar with Dashboards.
I can't find the Dashboard item properties in the doc.